# Why are Views misaligned?

Tags: swiftui

Any idea why the `Text` and `NavigationLink` views aren’t aligned to the left?

[image]

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        AccountActionsView()
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"), displayMode: .inline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AccountActionsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CardView()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Account actions")
                    .font(.custom("ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 16))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                NavigationLink("Account control") {
                    Form {
                        Button("Log out") {

                        }

                        Button("Delete account") {

                        }.foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                    .font(.custom("ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 14))
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Account control"), displayMode: .inline)
                }

                NavigationLink("Blocked users list") {

                }
            }
            .font(.custom("ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 14))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because by default are centered : you may use HStack and Spacer.

Comment: or add this to the VStack: `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)`

Comment: @PtitXav Even though I specified a `.leading` alignment on the VStack's constructor?

Comment: Also, why isn't the `NavigationLink`s' arrow shown?

Comment: VStack.alignment is for internal views, but it does not align VStack itself in outer container, so it remains shrank to content and centred, actually as it is seen on screenshot. Tip: give a .border(.red) for a container which you have doubts in during debug and you'll see its actual frame.